# Flex box grouping specific items based on screen resolution

Tags: html, flexbox

I have two layouts I would like to achieve using flex box, based on the user's screen resolution.  The problem is I can't seem to find a way to do it via flex, without having different html for each layout.

**Scenario 1:**  For screen resolutions larger than X, I would like to have this arrangement.

[image]

**Scenario 2**, for smaller screen resolutions, I would like the layout to be this:

[image]

**HTML**
My html looks something like

```
<div class="flex-container">
   <div class="flex-item1">Number 1</div>
   <div class="flex-item2>
      <p>Number 2/p>
      <div>Number 3</div>
   </div>
</div> --end container
```

**CSS**

```
   .flex-container {
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;
      flex-wrap:wrap;
   }
    .flex-item1 {
      width:35vw;
   }
    .flex-item2 {
       wdith:55vw;
   }
```

I grouped 2 and 3 together in a single div to force them to stack on top of each other under the first scenario, but that forces number 3 to stay on the right hand side on larger displays.  Instead, I need item number 3 to go to a new row and occupy `100vw` of the row on smaller displays, as shown in scenario 2.

I thought about two sets of html divs.  One with items 2 and 3 combined in the same flex box,  and one where they're in their own separate flex boxes, and using display:none/auto to turn them off and on, but I'm wondering it there's a better way to do this?

Comment: You're missing a < after "Number 3" in your HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with flexbox. Just make this your css and it will work:

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 100%;
}
.flex-item-1 {
    background: #7dc5ed;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
.flex-item-2 {
    background: #bb6fad;
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
.flex-item-3 {
    background: #6560ab;
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .flex-container {
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    .flex-item-1 {
        flex-basis: 50%;
    }
    .flex-item-2 {
        flex-basis: 50%;
    }
    .flex-item-3 {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect.  Thank you so much.  It just needed to be `max-width` instead of `min-width`.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this?

Yes, there is, i.e. the [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Layout you are trying to achieve is easily achievable using the CSS grid and the grid is more suitable for this kind of layout than flexbox. Grid will also simplify your HTML structure.

Following code snippet shows an example of the desired layout using CSS grid.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.item1 {
  background: peachpuff;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.item2 {
  background: magenta;
}

.item3 {
  background: blueviolet;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .item1 {
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  }
  .item3 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">Number 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Number 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Number 3</div>
</div>
```

Alternative approach using `grid-template-area` property of CSS grid.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'n1 n2' 'n1 n3';
}

.item1 {
  background: peachpuff;
  grid-area: n1;
}

.item2 {
  background: magenta;
  grid-area: n2;
}

.item3 {
  background: blueviolet;
  grid-area: n3;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-areas: 'n1 n2' 'n3 n3';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">Number 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Number 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Number 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, good solution but would require rewriting existing code substantially.  I voted up for your efforts.  Thanks.